# How do I rename multiple files by adding common name in-between the file name in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, rename

I have *n* number of files I want to rename by adding a common name in-between the existing name.

E.g.

```
"LRHP 100055"
"LRHP 200452"
"HRVG 500002_thumb"
```

I want to rename the above files to:

```
"LRHP 00100055"
"LRHP 00200452"
"HRVG 00500002_thumb"
```

In front of the number I want to add two zeros. My existing name should not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Batch Script Rename and Add Double Zeros to a Part of a File Name

In the below examples I used a [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop to set delimiters and tokens parsing file name parts and use those to set variables for later use with the [REN](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) command. I've also utilized the [Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) to handle the expanding of the variables set in the loop accordingly to be properly used (not parsed at runtime) with the rename command per iteration within the loop.

### Without a file Extension on the files to rename

```
@ECHO ON

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET SourceDir=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tester

FOR /F "TOKENS=1-2 DELIMS= " %%F IN ('DIR /B /A-D "%SourceDir%\*"') DO (
    SET "part1=%%~F" 
    SET "part2=%%~G" 
    SET "part3=%%~H"
    REN "%SourceDir%\!part1! !part2!" "!part1! 00!part2!"
)
GOTO EOF
```

[image]

### With a file extension on the files to rename

```
@ECHO ON

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET SourceDir=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tester

FOR /F "TOKENS=1-3 DELIMS=. " %%F IN ('DIR /B /A-D "%SourceDir%\*"') DO (
    SET "part1=%%~F" 
    SET "part2=%%~G" 
    SET "part3=%%~H"
    REN "%SourceDir%\!part1! !part2!.!part3!" "!part1! 00!part2!.!part3!"
)
GOTO EOF
```

[image]

---

### Further Resources

- [**FOR /F**](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [**Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion**](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [**REN**](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)

Answer (score 0):

[RenameFiles](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kd02ikef755rlx/renamefiles_v2.42_us.exe?dl=0) is my go-to Windows application for bulk file renaming.

- Unfortunately, the [original site](http://renamefiles.it-falke.com/) is no longer available, so I have linked to my own copy.
- [Archive of original site](http://web.archive.org/web/20110520081815/http://it-falke.com/software/renamefiles/us_description.php) for reference
- For your task, check the option "Insert string" `00` after character `5`:

[image]